# Railsのデータベース作成時にエラーが出てdb:createできません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql

railsアプリ開発のため、環境構築しているのですが、db:create時にエラーが出てデータベース作成ができません。
エラー文を検索してみたのですが、解決方法がわかりません。
どなたかご教示いただけないでしょうか。

```
olivemochi@DESKTOP-1BQH39C:~/testapp$ bin/rails db:create
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'olivemochi'@'localhost' to database 'testapp_development'
Couldn't create 'testapp_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'olivemochi'@'localhost' to database 'testapp_development'
/home/olivemochi/testapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/olivemochi/testapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'olivemochi'@'localhost' to database 'testapp_development'
/home/olivemochi/testapp/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/olivemochi/testapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

config/database.ymlのコードは以下です。

```
# MySQL. Versions 5.5.8 and up are supported.
#
# Install the MySQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-hashing.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8mb4
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: olivemochi
  password: "パスワード"
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: testapp_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: testapp_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: testapp_production
  username: testapp
  password: <%= ENV['TESTAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 2):

railsアプリ開発用に新規作成したユーザーの権限が何もないことが原因でした。rootユーザーでログインし、新規ユーザーへ権限を付与するとdb:createできました。